# Cloud-init module reboot process

Tags: centos, reboot, cloud-init

I create a instance with CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2. And then, i listed the modules with the 'chkconfig' command. In this list cloud-init module and other modules are on. When cloud-init is on, i tried to reboot the instance. It takes almost 5 min. It is too long. How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a network problem that prevents cloud-init to execute correctly. You can check it analysing cloud-init logs at `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

Which hypervisor/cloud are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to diagnose your problem with the limited information here.  There are a lot of recent changes in cloud-init with regard to OpenStack and CentOS.  We've recently added a [copr repository](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/cloud-init/cloud-init-dev/) for delivering cloud-init rpm builds from trunk.

If you are still having issues, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+filebug) in launchpad.

Follow the instructions there on what information to provide.
Feel free to ask for help in  irc on Freenode `#cloud-init`.

Comment: This should rather be a comment - not an answer.

Comment: Thats a perfectly valid suggestion, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question.

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should mis-use the answer button ;-)